# Simple perl regex search-replace script

Tags: regex, perl

With `sed` I can do something like:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/pattern/replacement/g
```

What's the simplest equivalent of the above in perl?

Comment: Wait, what `-f` flag is doing here?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov It makes the shebang line work. Think about it. The kernel runs `/bin/sed -nf scriptfile` and the script file becomes the argument to `-f` which is how you specify a script file for sed.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not  useful."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (my $m = <>) {
    $m =~ s/pattern/replacement/g;
    print $m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in perl it's just

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nw    

s/pattern/replacement/g
```

Comment: Running `echo patternpattern | ./my_script` gives 
`Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./my_script line 3.

Comment: put `$_ = <>;` before the replacement

Comment: It should have `-nw` instead of just `-w`. Which brings up the question: why did the original `sed` script have `-n` on it? That makes it an expensive no-op.

Answer (score 0):

It would be :

```
my $str = "fred";
$str =~ s/f/g/g;
```